# GAS: Is it possible to build html on server side

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm working on a complex synamic form with multiple inputs. I was thinking it might be easier to build in on the server side and inject into an HTMLservice form on the client side. I have:

```
  function buildOptionList(id, options) {

    //  http://jsfiddle.net/4pwvg/

    var document = '<div id="myDiv">Append here</div>';

  //  var myDiv = document.getElementById("myDiv");

    //Create array of options to be added
    //  var array = ["Volvo","Saab","Mercades","Audi"];
    var array = options;


    //Create and append select list
    var selectList = document.createElement("select");
    selectList.setAttribute("id", id);
    //  myDiv.appendChild(selectList);

    //Create and append the options
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      var option = document.createElement("option");
      option.setAttribute("value", array[i]);
      option.text = array[i];
      selectList.appendChild(option);
    }
    Logger.log(selectList)
    return selectList;

  }
```

But when I run it I get:

```
TypeError: Cannot find function createElement in object <div id="myDiv">Append here</div>
```

so I'm wondering if server side GAS has the ability to build HTML?

Comment: Yes. But it still is deployed on the client side so if you wish to call google script functions you may use google.script.run to communicate from client to server.  Read about it.  It's in the documentation.

Comment: Can you show me where?

Comment: Yes, it is possible, and there are "built in" ways to do this with templated HTML.  [Link to documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates)  It's faster to build HTML on the server, than in the browser.  You can't use DOM methods on the server.  There is no `appendChild(option)` method on the server.

Comment: So, if you are building HTML on the server, you may need to use string formulas, and program your own ways for building the HTML.

Comment: What  your doing in your example is not permitted unless your going to deploy it as javascript in an html document.  But you can create a string of html server side and send it to a javascript function and deploy it like this: document.getElementById().innerHTML= string.

Comment: Some times I use a file to build everything from the opening `<html> tag` to the body tag because that's easier to create javascript functions that way and then use this technique. `var ui=HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename); SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(ui.append(s), title);`

Comment: Ok, thank you guys this is very helpful. rather than reinvent the wheel are you aware of a simple all JS HTML builder as a library in GAS?

Comment: I'm not familiar with such a library.  I think it's pretty easy to build html and javascript with out such a library.

Comment: In answer to your question, here's the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/)

Comment: Guys, one more question , when you have created the html string on the server side . How do you pass it safely to the client side. Do you have to encode it in any way?

Comment: I'm looking at https://jonsuh.com/blog/javascript-templating-without-a-library/ for some examples on how to do this?